# Change color of number depending on number value

Tags: angular, if-statement

I have data json content on numbers in percentage , those numbers are start 0.0 . I want to change color of those number if highs , lowers or in middle .

my pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'precntColors'
})
export class PrecntColorsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    let d = value
    if (value >Math.round(0) && value<=Math.round(15)) {
      d="green"
    }
     else if (value>Math.round(16) && value<=Math.round(49)) {
      d="yellow"
    }
     else if (value>Math.round(50) && value <=Math.round(100)) {
      d="red"
    }
    return d; 

  }

}
```

html

```
<div [ngClass]='myda.percentage.canceled |precntColors'>

                </div>
```

When i run my app l got all number in green color ! and others colors are not showing . any ideas please ?

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo code on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: l hope , but l dont know how to use stackblitz.com

Comment: Go to https://stackblitz.com/ and select "Angular".rest everything is similar to normal angular project. Once done, click "save" and share the url

Comment: @ShashankVivek i will try

Comment: Cool, let me know once u create that demo. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I faced a lot of problem there . l puttted my file data json but l got `HttpErrorResponse` [https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vcy1oq] @ShashankVivek

Comment: what l understand is my code above correct  ?

Comment: It says :" The page you requested couldn't be found."

Comment: @ShashankVivek so is my code above correct ?

Comment: you are rounding integer numbers - unnecessary, but i think your value are in range (0,1) and you try to compare then with value in range (0, 100), and there's two gaps: 16 and 50

Comment: @DamianPioś so what is the best solution ?

Comment: ok, in stackBlitz i see that you pass values in range (0, 100), i would do it
if(value <=15){//green}
else if(value > 15 && <=50){//yellow}
else {red}

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify class names correctly and the pipe will convert the number value into **Class** Name

You can Checkout the Link For Code https://stackblitz.com/edit/pipe-for-number